# Usage of tense in present tense according to rules

Tags: grammar

It is a doubt which is related to tense.  using of 'do' form.
If the subject is singular the verb is going to have 's' or 'es.
When we use first person singular 'I' there we are not using 'does' but instead of using does we are using 'do' why? Is it wrong if we use 'does' after subject I?  please give me clarity for this question.

Thanking you

Comment: Why would you add an -s for the first person singular? You don't do that with any verbs, _do_ is not an exception. Your "rule" is wrong. "If the subject is singular the verb is going to have 's' or 'es" should be "If the subject is **third person** singular the verb is going to have 's' or 'es".

Answer (score 1):

In standard English, it is never grammatical to say *I does*.

English requires the verb to agree with the pronominal subject.  (Agreement wth noun subjects is slightly more complicated because of the existence of collective nouns, and so on.)  The reasons for a verb having separate forms (such as "do" and "does"), rather than using "do" for all persons, are no doubt historical.  In the past the number of inflections by person was greater - as is also the case in French, Spanish, Latin, and some other languages.

The *-s* or *-es* termination belongs to the third-[person](http://www.icaltefl.com/grammatical-person) singular.  In older English, the second-persons singular *thou* pronoun took verbs in *-(e)st*, but *I* cannot do so.

In some regional dialects, the *-s* termination *is* or can be used with *you* or *I*.   Upton et al., *A Survey of English Dialects* found "you uses", "you makes", "you eats" in English dialects.  But these forms are non-standard.

However, in the slang expression "[you pays your money and you takes your choice](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/you-pays-your-money-and-you-takes-your-choice-chance)", the non-standard forms are conventionally used.

(The only edge-case I can think of where a non-third-person-singular pronoun might effectively agree with "does" is the case of a compound disjunctive subject, e.g. "if you or he does it...".)

Answer (score 1):

> If the subject is singular the verb is going to have 's' or 'es.

No. The general English verb conjugation is something like:

> I walk.
>
> You walk.*
>
> He/She/It/One walks.
>
> We walk.
>
> They walk.
>
> You walk.

As you can see, the third-person singular adds an *s*, the rest do not.

So *do* is following exactly the same pattern:

> I do
>
> You do*
>
> He/She/It/One does
>
> We do
>
> They do
>
> You do.

*(Or *thou walkest* and *thou dost* but such use of the second-person singular is archaic in most regions and only found in prayer-books)